# Xamarin Android System.Drawing.Image alternative

Tags: android, image, xamarin.android, streamreader

Ideally would like to do something like

```
AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("test.png")))
{
    var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(sr.BaseStream);          
}
```

but `System.Drawing.Image class` does not exist with Xamarin Android.
How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found an alternative to overcome the missing `System.Drawing.Image`.

I have used the following:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("test.png")))
{
    BinaryReader binreader = new BinaryReader(sr.BaseStream);
    var allData = ReadAllBytes(binreader);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(allData, 0, allData.Length);
    imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

and

```
public static byte[] ReadAllBytes(BinaryReader reader)
{
    const int bufferSize = 4096;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
       byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
       int count;
       while ((count = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
             ms.Write(buffer, 0, count);
       return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```